# We can't import .svg files into Blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

We are new to using Blender and would really appreciate any help

We initially tried to import a .SVG file which appeared to load as details were displayed in the scene collection panel but it doesn't display on the plane
We tried to export a file out of Inkscape but had the same result when we tried to import that file

Are we missing something

Thanks for any help

Cheers
Rich

Comment: Make sure the object is in the view, sometimes imported SVGs can be very big or very small and maybe not in the world's center. Hit `A` to select all and then `Numpad .` to make sure you focus all selected objects in the viewport.

Comment: Hi Gordon
Thanks for the update - we tried it but the svg isn't being displayedeven though it lists it on the right

Comment: Well then, without the blend file that should contain the SVG (and maybe the SVG itself) or not even any screenshots it is more or less impossible to answer.

Comment: Hi Gordon
We are new here -  how would we upload the blender file and .svg file 
Thanks